# How do I know if a desktop GPU supports OpenGL ES?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, opengl

I have a *NVidia GTX 1050 TI* desktop GPU. Its [spec sheet](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/geforce-gtx-1050/) doesn't say whether it support OpenGL ES, but my preliminary tests suggest that it does.

The reason I want ES on a desktop is that I'm developing an app for an embedded system that only supports OpenGL ES 2.0 and I want to use the same API on my desktop machine (and I also want it to to work for my team members, who use a lot of different PCs).

**How do I know if *a given desktop GPU* supports OpenGL ES, other than write a GLES test app and try running it on the machine?**

The OSes we use are mainly Ubuntu and macOS.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for Ubuntu:

`glxinfo | grep 'version'`

Still need the answer for macOS.

Comment: I'd assumed OpenGL ES was a hardware spec, so if the card supports it, it really doesn't matter which OS you're running it on. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @music2myear: OpenGL ES may be a hardware spec, but the method to query for its support depends on the OS.